# How to use Entity Framework 5.0 with jQuery Datatable and fancybox

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-5, updatepanel, fancybox-2, datatables

I'm new to EF and jQuery Datatables. I've two entity called Country and State.
I'm binding my country grid like this

```
public void BindGrid()
    {
        using (var db = new DefaultCS())
        {
            var query = from c in db.CountryMasters
                        orderby c.CountryId ascending
                        select c;
            GridView1.DataSource = query.ToList();
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fnClickRedraw() {
        var oTable;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            TableTools.DEFAULTS.aButtons = ["copy", "csv", "xls", "pdf", "print"]
            oTable = $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID %>').dataTable({
                "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
                "iDisplayLength": 10,
                "aaSorting": [[0, "asc"]],
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "bRetrieve": true, "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "sDom": '<"top"i><"title">lt<"bottom"pf>',
                // ----  Print_Export_Copy  ----                
                "sDom": 'T<"clear"><"H"lfr>t<"F"ip>', "oTableTools": {
                    "sSwfPath": "../Content/DataTables-1.9.4/extras/TableTools/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
                },


                "bAutoWidth": true
            });

            oTable.$('tr').hover(function () { $(this).addClass("hover"); }, function () { $(this).removeClass("hover"); });
            oTable.$('tr').css("cursor", "pointer");
            oTable.$('td').click(function () {
                var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition(this);
                var aData = oTable.fnGetData(aPos[0]);
                $.fancybox({
                    'titleShow': false,
                    'width': 600,
                    'height': 460,
                    'href': 'CountryNew.aspx?Code=' + aData[0] + '',
                    'type': 'iframe',
                    'transitionIn': 'elastic',
                    'transitionOut': 'elastic',
                    'closeClick': false,
                    'helpers': {
                        overlay: {
                            closeClick: false,
                            showEarly: false
                        }
                    },
                    'overlayOpacity': 0.7,
                    'beforeClose': function () { document.getElementById("<%=btnRedraw.ClientID%>").click(); }
                });
            });
        });
        /* Get the rows which are currently selected */
        function fnGetSelected(oTableLocal) {
            return oTableLocal.$('tr.hover');
        }
    }
    function pageLoad(sender, args) {
        $("#btnCreate").fancybox({
            'titleShow': false,
            'width': 600,
            'height': 460,
            'type': 'iframe',
            'transitionIn': 'elastic',
            'transitionOut': 'elastic',
            'closeClick': false,
            'helpers': {
                overlay: {
                    closeClick: false,
                    showEarly: false
                }
            },
            'overlayOpacity': 0.7,
            'enableEscapeButton': false,
            'showCloseButton': false,
            'beforeClose': function () { document.getElementById("<%=btnRedraw.ClientID%>").click(); }
        });
    }

</script>
```

when I click on grid row Edit Country form popedup in fancybox and after editing I called a hidden button to rebind grid using update panel. Sam procedure for creating new country.
My question: How to insert new country without using update panel?
Thanks in advance.